# ksql json fieldname with a dash (-)

Tags: json, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

One of the field names in my JSON is "User-Agent".  KSQL doesn't like the dash when I try to create a stream with that field name.  I've tried single, double quotes, escaping it various ways--no luck.

How do I get that field from json in a topic to be in a KSQL stream?

Here's a log of some of my attempts:

```
ksql> create stream tmpstream (startTimeEpoch bigint, type VARCHAR, src VARCHAR, 'user-agent' varchar) with (KAFKA_TOPIC='foo', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
line 1:76: extraneous input ''user-agent'' expecting {'ADD', ...}

ksql> create stream tmpstream (startTimeEpoch bigint, type VARCHAR, src VARCHAR, user-agent varchar) with (KAFKA_TOPIC='foo', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
line 1:80: extraneous input '-' expecting {'ADD', ...}

ksql> create stream tmpstream (startTimeEpoch bigint, type VARCHAR, src VARCHAR, "user-agent" varchar) with (KAFKA_TOPIC='foo', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
ksql> select * from tmpstream;
Code generation failed for SelectValueMapper
Caused by: Line 1, Column 15: Expression "TMPSTREAM_user" is not an rvalue

ksql> drop stream tmpstream;
 Message
--------------------------------
 Source TMPSTREAM was dropped.
--------------------------------
ksql> create stream tmpstream (startTimeEpoch bigint, type VARCHAR, src VARCHAR, "user\-agent" varchar) with (KAFKA_TOPIC='foo', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
ksql> select * from tmpstream;
Code generation failed for SelectValueMapper
Caused by: Line 1, Column 15: Expression "TMPSTREAM_user" is not an rvalue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, having a dash within a field name is not supported.

KSQL issues

- [#1466](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1466)
- [#1165](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1165)

Please vote on the tickets which are more crticial for your use case.

---

One reason would be that all fields should adhere to Java variable naming conventions (minus capitalization rules). Meaning, alphanumeric and underscore characters are allowed.

---

The workarounds would require you to edit the producer code, or write a Kafka Streams task that can do a `map()` renaming to a supported field name structure.